# Does using non-SQL databases obviate the need for guarding against "SQL injection"?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection, nosql

This may seem like an obvious (or not so obvious) question, but let me explain. I'm coding up a Google App Engine site using Google's database technology, BigTable. Any App Engine coders will know that Google has its own limited query language called GQL. As a result, I am tempted not to do any checking for SQL (or GQL) injection in my app since I assume Google is not using a raw string query on its backend methods to fetch data.

Furthermore, libraries for DB technologies like CouchDB, MongoDB, and other object or document (aka NoSQL) databases seem to obviate the need to check if a malicious user is injecting database manipulation commands. They often have libraries that directly map the objects in the database to object in your language of choice. I know there are many SQL libraries that do this as well, but I assume that at some level they are combining parameters to run a query over a string, and thusly I must still use SQL Injection protection even with those frameworks.

Am I being short-sighted? Or is it only a matter of time till the next great DB system takes hold and then I will see injection into those systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Injection” holes are to do with text context mismatches. Every time you put a text string into another context of string you need to do encoding to fit the changed context. It seems seductively simple to blindly stuff strings together, but the difficulty of string processing is deceptive.

Databases with a purely object-based interface are immune to injection vulnerabilities, just like parameterised queries are in SQL. There is nothing an attacker can put in his string to break out of the string literal context in which you've put him.

But GQL specifically is not one of these. It's a string query language, and if you go concatenating untrusted unescaped material into a query like `"WHERE title='%s'" % title`, you're just as vulnerable as you were with full-on SQL. Maybe the limited capabilities of GQL make it more difficult to exploit that to completely compromise the application, but certainly not impossible in general, and in the very best case your application is still wrong and will fall over when people try to legitimately use apostrophes.

GQL has a parameter binding interface. Use it. Resist the allure of string hacking.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but GQL only allows SELECT queries, so assuming you start with 'SELECT ... FROM kind' there is nothing you could append to that to modify data, and nothing you could do other than select "rows" of the same entity kind that perhaps you weren't meant to see. If a user is allowed to see all "rows" of a particular kind, then there is no injection attack possible.

Comment: Sure, but SELECT can be dangerous enough in the wrong hands. The classic example is `WHERE username='...' AND password='...'` being expanded to `WHERE username='admin' OR username='x' AND password='x'` to get logged in to an admin account without the password, but depending on application logic there are many potential vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

SQL-subsets like GQL obviously still concern themselves with it -- but pure non-SQL databases like CouchDB, Voldemort, etc should put & get data without concern for SQL-injection-style attacks.

That however does not excuse you from doing content validation, because while it might not break the database, it may break your application and allow things like XSS (if it is a web app).

Answer (score 1):

Anytime data that is from or manipulated by user input is used to control the execution of code, there needs to be sanitization.  I've seen cases where code used user input to execute a command without sanitizing the input.  It hadn't been exploited, but if it had been it would have been a horrible attack vector.

Answer (score 1):

SQl Injection is only a subset of a type of security flaw in which any uncontrolled input gets evaluated.

techincally, you could "inject" javascript, among others.

Comment: "JavaScript Injection" is "XSS" or "Cross-Site Scripting."

Comment: @Justice, you don't have to be cross site to inject JS, you can do it locally with an input feild

Comment: To be sure, @Justice, I had XSS in mind, but didn't mention it on purpose, because that's a whole other can of worms :)